# Launching a file from within Atom, when that file type is already associated in the OS

Tags: python, atom-editor

I generally code in Python, under Windows 7. Just double clicking a .py file in any file manager launches that file in the command prompt, due to the .py file association with c:\Python27\python.exe

So my question is: Can I somehow launch the current file that I'm working on in Atom in the Windows's command prompt?
Without alt-tabing to the file manager and clicking the file I mean. 
I tried quite a lot of packages, most recommended being [script](https://atom.io/packages/script). But all packages that I've tried execute the file in the Atom's console, which currently does not support `stdin`(can't input data through commands like `raw_input()`). And that is really what I require the most at the moment.

Is there an easy workaround? I've been at it for a few hours and can't seem to be able to find a solution, literally anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...eventually found an answer myself. If anyone needs this feature under windows, just install [run-in-terminal](https://github.com/pohmelie/run-in-terminal). In the plug-in's settings go to line `Terminal with arguments` box and enter `start /D {working_directory} D:\Python27\python.exe {file_path}`. And simply press F5 to run the code from the main editor's window. PERFECT!!!!

PS. Might want to change D: to C: depending where your python file is.
Good Luck!!
<3 Atom